# Component Creation How-to

Tags: joomla, module, plugins, components, creation

I want to create a component that will allow me to install other components, modules, and plugins that i personally use all the time.  I will need to be able to change these modules, components, and plugins at anytime but updating the components and etc..  that i use and be able to add more plugins and etc as well.  I would like this Component because it takes too much time to install them all individually and on multiple sites as a web designer.  I also would need to have some instruction on how to add subtract plugins, modules, components, and etc.  I am ok with not a total integration i would like to be able to just host the install file on my server with a link to my server where the file is located.

If anyone can help with this please do.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a direct answer more of a personal workaround ( I do this on local host).

I create a site for example Joomlabase, when it asks for DB name call it Joomlabase  then add my extensions

then when I need a copy

1) copy and paste the folder named Joomlabase in Windows Explorer to a new name.

2) go into Phpmydmin copy the joomlabase DB to the same name as the new site name.

3) DO a search and replace of Joomlabase to new site name in config.php file (there should be 5 changes) and your done.

For me it saves a lot of time because  in admin alone I use at least 12 different extensions

Answer (score 0):

There is a Joomla admin component called "Akeeba". It creates a snapshot of your files and database which you can easily deploy to another server. I use it often when pushing a new site to production from a QA server.

http://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup-core-for-joomla/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too broad, and the simple answer is that it would take much much much more work to maintain this 'super component' than you are currently spending simply installing the extensions separately when you need them.

The other answers here don't answer your question, but they provide some decent solutions to your actual problem.